# How should I handle measurement error in logistic/probit regression and what are its effects?

Tags: regression, logistic, measurement-error, measurement

I am concerned with the problem where dependent discrete variable $R$ is to be modelled by continuous predictor $X^*$, which is subject to measurement error $u$ of the form $$X^*=X+u$$ ($X$ being the true score). Let's assume $N(\mu_u,\sigma_u)$ as error distribution.

I have now two questions.

1. Let us suppose I know $E(X)$, $V(X)$ as well as $\mu_u$ and $\sigma_u$. Is it possible to give a closed form description for the effect of measurement error on parameters of logit and probit models?
2. Which models could be used to control for measurement error in estimation?